# Why does this script that uses tcpreplay not wait for user input?

Tags: perl, tcpreplay

The following snippet will only wait for the user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the first time; after that, it cycles through all the rest of the `.pcap` files without waiting for user input.

```
$| = 1;

while (<*.pcap>) {
    print "$_";
    <STDIN>;

    system("tcpreplay -i eth0 -M 20 $_");
}
```

Why doesn't this wait for user input on every loop iteration?

Comment: This works fine for me `perl -e'while ( <*.txt> ) { print; <> }'` printing one file name for each press of Enter. Can you test it on your system, please?

Comment: I've tested this, and it works for a simple case, but definitely breaks with the `system` call to `tcpreplay`. It just skips right past the <STDIN> anything beyond the first pass, and when assigning it to a variable, is only defined on pass one.

Comment: Thanks guys. There is something strange about "tcpreplay". Wonder if there is any workaround.

Comment: Does ir make a difference if you chomp $_?

Comment: @sidyll: no, it doesn't

Comment: $_ here doesn't a newline at the end, but you pointed out a bug here,  <STDIN> will overwrite $_.  Thanks.

Comment: Please use `use strict;` in your script. Your use of `$f = $_;` indicates that you are not using `strict`.

Comment: That's true. Thanks @bart for pointing it out!

Comment: @codingFun: A bare `<>` or `<STDIN>` *won't* overwrite `$_` -- the value entered is simply discarded. It's only within a `while` condition like `while ( <> ) { ... }` that `$_` is used to store the input

Comment: Thanks @Borodin for pointing it out, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you care about `tcpreplay` output? Redirecting stdout and stderr seems to fix this problem:

```
system("tcpreplay -i eth0 -M 20 $_ >/dev/null 2>&1");
```

Alternatively, you can use this to capture `tcpreplay` output:

```
my $tcpreplay_output = `tcpreplay -i eth0 -M 20 $_ 2>&1`;
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, it works great.  Wonder why the original one behave the way it did.

Answer (score 2):

[`tcpreplay` sets STDIN to use non-blocking I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16402813/176646), which causes reads to return an error immediately if no data is available. You can see this by checking the return value of `readline`:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

$| = 1;

while (<*.pcap>) {
    say;
    die "readline error: $!" if ! defined <STDIN>;

    system("tcpreplay -i eth0 $_") == 0
        or die "tcpreplay failed: $?";
}
```

After the first call to `tcpreplay`, this dies with the message:

> readline error: Resource temporarily unavailable at ./replay line 10, <STDIN> line 1.

This corresponds to errno `EAGAIN`, which [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) returns if a file descriptor marked as non-blocking would have to block to wait for I/O.

---

If your system implements `fcntl`, you can get around this by setting STDIN to use blocking I/O after every call to `tcpreplay`:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Fcntl;

$| = 1;

while (<*.pcap>) {
    say;
    die "readline error: $!" if ! defined <STDIN>;

    system("tcpreplay -i eth0 $_") == 0
        or die "tcpreplay failed: $?";

    # Reset STDIN to use blocking I/O
    my $flags = fcntl(STDIN, F_GETFL, 0) 
        or die "Couldn't get flags for STDIN: $!";
    fcntl(STDIN, F_SETFL, $flags & ~O_NONBLOCK) 
        or die "Couldn't set flags for STDIN: $!";
}
```

This is just a workaround, though; `tcpreplay` should be fixed.